# There are no errors in the program code, all the writing of the syntax is correct but when run in the vscode terminal it doesn't show anything

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

Before getting to the root of the problem I will show my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_TITLE_BOOK 1000
#define MAX_AUTHOR_BOOK 1000
#define MAX_CATEGORY_BOOK 1000
#define MAX_NAME_BORROW 1000

typedef struct 
{
    char title[MAX_TITLE_BOOK];
    char author[MAX_AUTHOR_BOOK];
    char category[MAX_CATEGORY_BOOK];
    int code;
}Book ;

typedef struct 
{
    char name[MAX_NAME_BORROW];
    int id;
    int codeBorrow;
    int dateBorrow[3];
    int dateReturn[3];
}Borrow;



void add(Book x[], int y){ 
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < y; i++){
        printf("Menu ke-%d", i+1);
        printf("\nEnter the Book Title: ");
        scanf("%s", x[i].title);
        printf("\nEnter Book Author: ");
        scanf("%s", x[i].author);
        printf("\nEnter the Book Category: ");
        scanf("%s", x[i].category);
        printf("\nEnter Book Code: ");
        scanf("%d", &x[i].code);
    }
}

void save(Book x[], int y){ 
    FILE* f_book;
    f_book = fopen("book-data.txt", "w");
    if(f_book == NULL){
        printf("\nUnable to open file, check file location or permissions\n");
        return;
    }
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < y; i++){
        fprintf(f_book, "%s %s %s %d\n", x[i].title, x[i].author, x[i].category, x[i].code);
    }
    printf("\nData successfully saved to database\n");
    fclose(f_book);
}



int main(){
    char username[10] = "admin", password[10] = "admin";
    char checkUser[10],checkPass[10];
    int menu, limit = 0, total_books = 0, dataBook;
    Book s_book[1000];

    do{
        printf("\t\n================================");
        printf("\n\tLogin Page");
        printf("\t\n================================");
        printf("\n");
        printf("\nMasukan Username: ");
        scanf("%s", checkUser); 
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\nMasukan Password: ");
        scanf("%s", checkPass); 
        fflush(stdin);

        if(strcmp(checkUser, username) == 0 && strcmp(checkPass, password) == 0){
            printf("\nSuccessfully Login");
            break;
        }else{
            printf("\nUsername or Password Wrong!");
        }
        limit++;
    }while(limit < 3);

    if(limit > 3){
        printf("\nToo many request, try again in 30 seconds.");
    }

    if(limit < 3){
        do{
            printf("\n");
            printf("\n\t=================================");
            printf("\n\tSystem Library IT Telkom Surabaya");
            printf("\n\t=================================");
            printf("\n1. Add Data");
            printf("\n2. Read Data");
            printf("\n3. Change/Update Data");
            printf("\n4. Search Data");
            printf("\n5. Sort Data");
            printf("\n6. Borrow Book");
            printf("\n7. Return Book");
            printf("\n0. Exit");
            printf("\nMenu: ");
            scanf("%d", &menu);
            fflush(stdin);
            
            switch(menu){
            case 1:
                printf("\nInput Total Buku: ");
                scanf("%d", &dataBook);
                fflush(stdin);
                add(s_book, dataBook);
                save(s_book, dataBook);
                break;
            default:
                printf("\nMenu not available, re-enter");
                break;
        }
    }while(menu != 0);
}
return 0;
}
```

so my problem is why my divscode terminal doesn't want to issue login program and only blank in terminal. like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROCHb.png). Idk why this is happen, this errro happen after i make procedure for case 1, that is add and save.

I want my code to run normally, like can input and show the output

Comment: So does it work on "normal" terminal? If you run `.\system-library-2`?

Comment: Code that passes through the compiler and linker without errors or warnings might still not be correct. There might be logical error. There might be misuse of pointers. Uninitialized variables, etc. Many chances of getting *undefined behavior*.

Comment: On a different note, passing an input-only stream (like `stdin`) to `fflush` is explicitly mentioned in the C specification as leading to undefined behavior. One compiler have added it as a non-standard and non-portable extension. Please try to avoid such things.

Comment: Seems like a problem with the terminal rather than the source. It is however good practice to put `'\n'` at the end of each printf since in some terminals line feed flushes the stdout. And as for `fflush(stdin)` that's undefined behavior and will not work.

Comment: Also regarding your login handling, what happens when `limit == 3` and the loop ends? The program will still continue as if there was a valid login attempt. :)

Comment: if limit == 3 the program will do a break, I forgot to add it

Comment: For purposes of this exercise, move `Book s_book[1000];` out of stack, by moving it to be just _before_ `main`, outside the function. It's probably not a problem here, but still a 3 megabyte array is uncomfortably large for stack. As a bonus, it will be automatically initialized to 0. Note: normally you'd use malloc for something like this.

Comment: Check return value of every `scanf` call, and (as a first version) abort on parse errors. Write helper input functions for different purposes, and put `scanf`+error checking in them.

Comment: what is wrong with using a debugger to see if you step onto some of the print statements

Comment: strip down the program till you get some output, then build it back up

Comment: what should happen if I enter a username 25 characters long, most effective is if you put the `flush` after a `printf`, do I get the `Too many request` if I try 3 times

Comment: how do you expect to read the database, if I run the program again am I able to add new books